# Change dropdown value based on another dropdown using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a dropdown like this :

```
<select id="edit-submitted-main-wrapper-filed-main-information-wrapper-userinfo-city" name="" class="form-select">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
<option value="1">B</option>
<option value="2">A</option>
<option value="3">C</option>
</select>
```

and this

```
<select id="select-province" name="" class="form-select">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
<option value="1">f</option>
<option value="2">g</option>
<option value="3">h</option>
<option value="4">k</option>
<option value="5">l</option>
<option value="6">m</option>
<option value="7">n</option>
</select>
```

i don't have any access to html for adding data-attribute for second dropdown .

**I know how to change second dropdown value based on first dropdown value.**

The question is : is this possible to show second dropdown value like this :

```
    $("#select-province").children('option[value=1] > option[value=4]').show();
```

using jquery ?

Comment: `.show()` plays with the `display` css property. You will have to use _selected_ `attr` or `prop` to choose the option if `option[value=1] > option[value=4]` yield any results. The selection does seem valid at first glance, but need to be tested :)

Comment: Which value you want to be selected in second dropdown.any conditions?

Comment: i want to show some value based on another dropdown no matter is value selected or not .

Comment: I don't think anyone is understanding what it is exactly you want...give us a case won't you?